# Fill area between two lines using higcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, area

Good morning everybody,

I'm trying to fill the area between two lines using highcharts. I've checked the other answers to similar questions but the truth is that I couldn't solve my problem. I think it's a silly problem but I can't find the solution, so I hope you can help me.
I have two series, one of them is a straight line and the other one is a line with variable values. I want to fill the area comprehended between both of them. For this I'm using an arearange serie but the result is shown at it follows:

[image: My Chart]

But what I want is to fill the green zones in this image:

[image]

For this, as I said, I'm using an arearange serie using as data values de difference between red line and blue line (if red line is greather than blue one), but the first image is what I have.

Dataset code:

```
var dataRange= [];
dataBlue=JSON.parse(dataBlue);
dataRed=JSON.parse(dataRed);

for(var i=0;i<dataBlue.length;i++){
    if(dataBlue[i] < dataRed[i]){
        console.log("LOW: "+dataBlue[i]);
        console.log("HIGH: "+dataRed[i]);
        dataRange[i]=[dataBlue[i],dataRed[i]];
    }else{
        dataRange[i]=[0,0];
    }
}
```

My series code:

```
 series: [{
            name: "Blue line",
            //type:'line',
            dataLabels:false,
            data: JSON.parse(dataBlue)
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Red Line',
            color: "#DB1818",
            dataLabels: false,
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            visible: true,
            data: JSON.parse(dataRed)
        },
        {
            type: 'arearange',
            name: 'range',
            data: dataRange,
            dataLabels: false,

        }]
```

Thanks you all in advance.

Comment: You can use threshold parameter of your series for changing the position of threshold for drawing area. Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/ghc5v8hy/1/

Comment: HI @GrzegorzBlachliński, here you have a working example https://jsfiddle.net/d5zrwLa4/1/

Comment: As I can see you didn't use zones, like I did. Here you can find working example: https://jsfiddle.net/d5zrwLa4/2/

Comment: Thanks you so much @GrzegorzBlachliński It almost worked for me. I still have the zones above the dashed line coloured in black. I don't know why it doesn't work fine with my original code because I did the same as in the last example using my data. Best solution I found was set the "color" attribute in zones to the same area chart's color.  

EDITED: I managed to solve it using the latest highcharts version.